# linux centos 7 - create delete accounts

Tags: linux, centos, vmware

I am running centos 7 as virtual machine through vmware, the default user was:

```
unsername: osboxes.org
password:  osboxes.org
```

I created new user (john), then removed osboxes.org along its home directory using the `-r` flag as described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-a-centos-7-server)

Now I am logged in as john, but I can still see osboxes in the terminal:

```
[john@osboxes ~]$
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but depending on your `$PS1` (prompt variable) that value will differ. Try typing `hostname -f` and `echo $PS1` to check. Looks a lot like a user@host prompt to me. See: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html to learn more about $PS1.

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing looks a lot like the default `$PS1` user shell prompt on Linux: `[user@host dir]$`.

## Listing your current settings:

To find out what your current $PS1 is set to, type:

```
echo $PS1
```

To list your current hostname, type:

```
hostname
hostname -f # For FQDN
```

To list your current user, type:

```
id
whoami
```

## Prompt values:

Your `$PS1` will look something like this: `[\u@\h \W]\$` (redhat 'default'). Here's what that means:

```
\u  The name of the logged-in user
\h  The hostname up to the first '.'
\$  Shows a $ for a regular user or # for root user
```

See `man bash` for more information.

## Reference:

- [Howto: Change / Setup bash custom prompt (PS1)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) - bash prompt tutorial
- [Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) - List of bash prompt sequences
- [Bash PS1 Generator](https://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html) - create your own custom prompt
- [List all users in the system](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-users-command/) - find out more about Linux users
- [Change and set the hostname on CentOS 7](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-redhat-centos-7-change-hostname-command/) - In case you wish to change the hostname.